# how to shutdown a tomcat created with tomcat7:exec-war

Tags: maven, tomcat7

I am using the exec-war goal of tomcat7-maven-plugin version 2.1 (not latest version 2.2 because of bug [MTOMCAT-263](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MTOMCAT-263) breaking that goal) to create a jar artifact which contains a tomcat 7 with the deployed war of my project. Works fine. The whole thing (server with war) is started like this:

```
java -jar foo.jar
```

https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.1/tomcat7-maven-plugin/exec-war-mojo.html

https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.1/executable-war-jar.html

Now I am wondering how to shutdown nicely. Who knows?

I have to integrate it into some CMD windows batch script.

Is it possible to stop it using a regular Tomcat? I tried

```
java -classpath "bin/*" org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap stop
```

but that lead to

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: 
connect at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
```